# Video processing recommendations

Tags: c#, video, opencv, image-stabilization

I am starting a new project were I will be getting a video input and I will have to add several itens in the video..some lines and real time information. Since the camera will be in a shaking enviroment, I will probably need also to add some sort of video stabilization as well.
I plan to use C# in the project, since it's the language I know better, so I wanted to know which APIs should I look for? OpenCV is just fine or are there any better choices?
I am pretty new in computer vision, so any advice is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV is bar-none the defacto computer vision library.  It is packed full of functions to make your life easier.

With respect to image stabilization, [Stackoverflow has answered possible approaches to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431434/video-stabilization-with-opencv).  Most of the time, you want to extract robust local feature descriptors and use them to perform [registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration) on consecutive image frames.

Comment: The camera will be in an airplane, so I am afraid the software can go nuts because of the airplane motion, thinking it is some kind of shake...is this easy to resolve?