# Which of types Mat or vector<Point2f> is better to use with function estimateRigidTransform()?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, image-stabilization

As known, we can pass to the function `estimateRigidTransform()` two parameters with one of two types: [`Mat estimateRigidTransform(InputArray src, InputArray dst, bool fullAffine)`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#Mat%20estimateRigidTransform(InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20dst,%20bool%20fullAffine))

1. `cv::Mat frame1, frame2;`
2. `std::vector<cv::Point2f> frame1_features, frame2_features;`

I.e., for example, to implement video-stabilization (shake remove) we can use one of two approach:

1. with `cv::Mat`: [video stabilization using opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622608/video-stabilization-using-opencv)

```cpp
cv::Mat frame1 = imread("frame1.png");
cv::Mat frame2 = imread("frame2.png");
Mat M = estimateRigidTransform(frame1, frame2, 0);
warpAffine(frame2, output, M, Size(640,480), INTER_NEAREST|WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
```

2. with `std::vector<cv::Point2f> features;`

```cpp
vector <uchar> status;
vector <float> err;

std::vector <cv::Point2f> frame1_features, frame2_features;
cv::Mat frame1 = imread("frame1.png");
cv::Mat frame2 = imread("frame2.png");
goodFeaturesToTrack(frame1 , frame1_features, 200, 0.01, 30);
goodFeaturesToTrack(frame2 , frame2_features, 200, 0.01, 30);
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(frame1 , frame2, frame1_features, frame2_features, status, err);

std::vector <cv::Point2f> frame1_features_ok, frame2_features_ok;
for(size_t i=0; i < status.size(); i++) {
 if(status[i]) {
  frame1_features_ok.push_back(frame1_features[i]);
  frame2_features_ok.push_back(frame2_features[i]);
 }
}

Mat M = estimateRigidTransform(frame1_features_ok, frame2_features_ok, 0);
warpAffine(frame2, output, M, Size(640,480), INTER_NEAREST|WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
```

Which of these approach is better to use, and why?

I.e. which of types `Mat` or `vector<Point2f>` is better to use with function estimateRigidTransform()?

Comment: first version doesnt give you any control about the way HOW the rigid transform is computed. So it might be comfortable to use, but I can't tell anything about the quality of the estimated transformation in this scenario. I prefer using the 2nd version with my own point correspondences (not necessarily from optical flow).

Comment: @Micka  "not necessarily from optical flow", but, for example, from what?

Comment: Sift or other keypoints, block-matching, dense-matching, or any other "correspondences"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case OpenCV will perform implicitly a `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()` inside the function `estimateRigidTransform()`. See the implementation in [lkpyramid.cpp @ line 1383](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp#L1383).

This is the only difference between the two methods. If finding correspondences between `frame1` and `frame2` matters then use version #2 otherwise #1.