# How to stabilize Webcam video?

Tags: c++, opencv

I`m new in OpenCV. I want to use optical flow method to stabilize Webcam Real-time video. Actually, I can stabilize video file but when I tried to apply Webcam it does not work.

Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

Yesterday I just did some works (in `Python`) on this subject, main steps are:

1. use `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack` to find good corners.
2. use `cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` to track the corners.
3. use `cv2.findHomography` to compute the homography matrix.
4. use `cv2.warpPerspective` to transform video frame.

But the result is not that ideal now, may be I should choose `SIFT  keypoints` other than `goodFeatures`.

---

Source:

[image]

Stabilize the car:

[image]