# How to read gif from url using opencv (python)

Tags: python, opencv

I can read jpg file using cv2 as

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib
url = r'http://www.mywebsite.com/abc.jpg'
req = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
arr = np.asarray(bytearray(req.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(arr,-1)
cv2.imshow('abc',img)
```

However, when I do it with gif file, it returns an error:

```
error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: As far as I know, OpenCV does not support GIF files... try using PIL (pillow) to load it and then pass it to OpenCV. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python) you have another question about how to get an image with PIL and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134892/convert-image-from-pil-to-opencv-format) to convert to OpenCV

Comment: Thank you very much, api55.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Steps:

1. Use `urllib` to read the gif from web,
2. Use `imageio.mimread` to load the gif to `nump.ndarray`(s).
3. Change the channels orders by `numpy` or `OpenCV`.
4. Do other image-processing using `OpenCV`

Code example:

```
import imageio
import urllib.request

url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/lui1A.gif"
fname = "tmp.gif"

## Read the gif from the web, save to the disk
imdata = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
imbytes = bytearray(imdata)
open(fname,"wb+").write(imdata)

## Read the gif from disk to `RGB`s using `imageio.miread` 
gif = imageio.mimread(fname)
nums = len(gif)
print("Total {} frames in the gif!".format(nums))

# convert form RGB to BGR 
imgs = [cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) for img in gif]

## Display the gif
i = 0

while True:
    cv2.imshow("gif", imgs[i])
    if cv2.waitKey(100)&0xFF == 27:
        break
    i = (i+1)%nums
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Note. *I use the gif in my another answer. [Video Stabilization with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431434/video-stabilization-with-opencv/47483926#47483926)*

The result:

```
>>> Total 76 frames!
```

One of the gif-frames displayed:

[image]

Comment: You can also use the library gif2numpy. You can find it at https://github.com/bunkahle/gif2numpy

Comment: @bunkus I check your library `gif2numpy`. It's a nice library based on `kaitaistruct` binary struct descriptor. And it'll be better if it supports multi-frames gif. Great job!

Comment: Well it now supports also multiple frames. Give it a try and let me know if it works for you

Comment: @bunkus I try to use [git2numpy](https://github.com/bunkahle/gif2numpy) to read a multi-frames gif(such as Images/Rotating_earth.gif), it successfully read 44 frames. Nice. While, there exists one issue, I'll comment on the project. Thank you for you job.

Comment: gif2numpy has been bugfixed in version 1.2. Images now come out without missing pixels, latest version on github: https://github.com/bunkahle/gif2numpy

Comment: @bunkus `Now, the gif2numpy works fine for multi-frames gif` except the time costing 60ms(imageio) vs 
 6000ms(gif2numpy).  And `jit(numba)`、 `vector operation(numpy)` 、`Cython or C` will accelerate the parsing speed. You can add a new answer using `gif2numpy` under this SO question.