# How to stabilize video with OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, video-processing, opencv, python

I have a video which is taken with a moving camera and contains objects. I would like to stabilize the video, so that all objects will remain in the same position in the video feed.

How can I do this with OpenCV?

i.e. For example, if I have two images prev_frame and next_frame, how do I transform next_frame so the video camera appears stationary like in the next example.

example:

[image]

[image]

there are some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431434/video-stabilization-with-opencv) but most of them irrelevant anymore because the lack of code examples or methods and libraries that doesn't exist anymore.

thanks.

Comment: there are programs that will do this. even ffmpeg has a filter for this. do *you* really need to implement this? if you do, it will involve optical flow and/or feature matching. you will need to understand homographies and camera calibration (even if you don't need to calibrate a camera here)